# Can't access a district page by clicking on name

Tags: html, typescript

I need to do so when you click on the text to move to the page according to the coordinates that are in the code

```
 <text id="MDA1613_short" x="110" y="95" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" fill="#6C6C6C" stroke="#6C6C6C"
            font-size="24px"
            font-weight="400" letter-spacing="0.2em" (click)="onMouseText($event)" [attr.shortName]="districtEnum.BR">{{districtEnum.BR}}
      </text>
      <text id="MDA1614_short" x="320" y="115" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" fill="#6C6C6C"
            stroke="#6C6C6C" font-size="24px"
            font-weight="400" letter-spacing="0.2em" (click)="onMouseText($event)" [attr.shortName]="districtEnum.DN">{{districtEnum.DN}}
      </text>

onMouseText(event) {
    const x = event.clientX;
    const y = event.clientY;
    this.router.navigate(['/map']);
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the question; are anchor links perhaps what you're looking for? And can you add a reproducible code snippet?

Comment: I need to put an array with all those values

Comment: I'm still unsure; it sounds like you have text of district names at the top of the page, and when you click the name, you want it to scroll down the page to that district's information. Is that correct? And is the district's information more text or is it on a map or image?

Comment: I'm on a map, and when I click I need to move to another page with the data by code

Comment: So when you click the district on the map, you want to go to a different url that has information about that district?

Comment: Yes, that's right, that's what I need

Comment: And what happens currently when you click the district? (Also, I suggest updating your question with this information so it's easier for others to help you.)

Comment: when I click on the district it moves me to another page with all the data, but the problem is that when I click on the text in the district nothing happens, and now I want to do so when I click on the text to move to the page with all the data

Comment: And the code above has all the data Id, x, y and now I need to make an array with the data above and be able to navigate through them